# Find if a set fits another set, by applying its correspondent score to an equation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

### Summary

Given that I have finite elements, each element has its score value, and a set A with some of those elements, which I can sum all the elements score to have a result, is it possible to determine if a set B is a subset of A or equals A, by an equation, using the scores?

### A real world scenario

[big windows, white color, black color, pool, garden, garage, two floors]

[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

My elements are the house features with their correspondent score.
A set would be a house.

I have a finite list of house features represented in the first array. Also, each feature has its value, defined in the second array respectively.

A buyer wants to find a house with big windows, garage and two floors. So, if I sum his features requirements values, I will have 1+32+64= **97**. Then I have a house with the features big windows, white color, garage and two floors. The sum of this house features is 1+2+32+64=**99**. Even though the 2 sums are not the same, that house fits the buyer conditions.

1. Is it possible to create an equation that given a house with its features, and a buyer with their requirements, by its result I can find out it the house fits the buyer needs?
2. Also, is it possible to apply *AND* / *OR* / *AND NOT IN* / *OR NOT IN* conditions to the buyer requirements? Ie. Big windows, (white color or has a pool) but not garage.

### What I am trying to achieve

Given a rule, which is a combination of house features, find a function that results in a unique score for the rule.

Given a set, a house, find a function that when applied to a rule, results true if the house fits the rule (a house can have more features than the rule), or false if the house doesn't fit the rule.

If this is an existing topic in mathematics, may I get its name so I can study it?

### Undergoing solution

As @SenZen suggested, if each feature has an unique prime number, I can find if a set of features fits a house by dividing their products. For the NOT condition I do the same but applying the reversed truth table (I want to find !(true), which is, it cant be divisible by the product of NOT primes).

The blocker that I face is, mapping features to a prime number. I have 5K features, and sometimes new ones can be added. So given a prime number, I will need to find the next prime to attribute to the new feature.

Comment: Adding up the numerical codings for the features isn't going to work in your example: $5 + 8 = 13$, but a house with a pool and a garden isn't necessarily quiet. You can use numbers and arithmetic to talk about finite sets . Can you provide us a bit more information about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @RobArthan my bad, it is not fibonacci but 8 bits. The problem is to find in bucket of sets (all the houses in a city) which of them fits in a rule (rule been the AND / OR combination of features defined by the buyer) in a mathematic way.

Comment: For (1), what's wrong with your method? Sum up the values and if they're equal, it fits, if not, then it doesn't.

Comment: Using powers of $2$ is going to make things a bit better (although $2^8 = 256$, not $254$). This will give you a test for **exact** matches as pointed out by @SenZen. It won't help with subset matching. Again, we would more information to give you a better answer.

Comment: For (2), notice you've already implicitly defined AND. For NOT, a non-elegant solution would be to simply define NOT (property) as it's own property, provided we rely on house buyers not asking for a pool and not a pool. For OR, just compute the different cases and if the given house is any of those, output true, else, false.

Comment: There is a disparity between the summary and real world scenario. In the real world scenario, you ask for only exact matching, but in the summary you ask also for subset matching. What do you want a subset matching function for?

Comment: @SenZen sorry I couldnt find a better way to express the problem. The subset is that if a rule has a score X a matching house score can be >X. If I only ask for a pool, and you give me a house with all the features, the condition is satisfied then output true.

Comment: @TiagoBrench that is more interesting!

Comment: You could assign each property a prime, then instead of adding, multiply them. Assign this value to the "rule". This "rules"'s value will be unique by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and you can test if a house fits by checking if the " rule"'s value divides the house's property value, calculated the same way.

Comment: @SenZen That is awesome. I tested and it indeed seems to work, but I wonder how to treat rules with not. For instance, rule = [white, !pool] ? Would that be, divisible by white value, but divisible by pool value?

Comment: @TiagoBrenck For NOT, my inelegant solution above should still work. Assign !pool it's own prime value and just treat it as if it were an independent property like pool itself.